# Pyperclip copy and dividing the results

Tags: python, copy-paste, pyperclip

I'm having some issues with my code not dividing the copied answers and instead giving me string errors.

```
for x in range(5):
    time.sleep(3)
    coordinates = (pyperclip.paste())
    print(coordinates/2)
```

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'objc.pyobjc_unicode' and 'int'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used pyperclip.copy("1234") and the string was a number then you could do this

```
for x in range(5):
    time.sleep(3)
    coordinates = int(pyperclip.paste())
    print(coordinates/2)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a look on the main page of official site : https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/

you have then the following code :

```py
>>> import pyperclip
>>> pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
>>> pyperclip.paste()
'The text to be copied to the clipboard.'
```

**paste** function does not essentially gives coordinates but you get back what has been copied.

If you copy a text, you can not divide a text by an integer.
If you copy a number, let keep in mind that this number is a string until you defines it like a integer.
For this you use the int() function. Let's say you copy a '2' :

```py
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('2')
print(int(pyperclip.paste())/2)
```

Anyway in your case it won't work like you are trying to get coordinates.
coordinates = (x , y) like it will generate the exception

```py
c=(1,2)
c/2
Retraçage (dernier appel le plus récent) : 
  Shell Python, prompt 23, line 1
builtins.TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Let's say coordinates is the string '(1,2)', you could have then the new coordinates calculation function :

```
coordinates = '(1,2)'

def new_coord(coordinates, func):
    return tuple(map(func, coordinates.strip("()").split(",")))
    
print(new_coord(coordinates, func=lambda c: int(c)/2))
# (0.5, 1.0)
```